# Make with numpy an array that contains every cell its index multiplication, without loops

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I want to make a function which get an int called "n" (4 for example),
and make with it a numpy array which every cell contains its index multiplication.
I want to make it without any loops.
For example, for a int of 4:

```
index_check(4)
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0, 2, 4, 6],
[0, 3, 6, 9]]
```

what i tried to do was to use the commands np.arrange , np.reshape, np.tile , but i got stuck.
thank you very much

Comment: Post your code.  For example, the first thing you need is an n x n matrix.  Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.multiply.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) on range-array -

```
In [41]: n = 4

In [42]: np.multiply.outer(np.arange(n), np.arange(n))
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

Shorter one with unpacking and `range` instead -

```
In [44]: np.multiply.outer(*[range(n)]*2)
Out[44]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in function in numpy that provides you with indices and multiply row-index to col-index using `np.multiply` as follows:

```
np.multiply(*np.indices((4,4)))
```

output:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 2 4 6]
 [0 3 6 9]]
```